# Travis CI for Android

Tags: android, travis-ci

Trying to get started with Travis CI for my Android projects. First I set up dummy project with Android Bootstrap, and added a the yml file from square's otto project - modified to have my username and repo name.

My build fails with the error "[/home/travis/build.sh: line 94: android: command not found](https://travis-ci.org/f2prateek/FoodBot), even when [square's project builds fine](https://travis-ci.org/square/otto).

The error seems to indicate that the path isn't set properly, in spite of having these lines in my .travis.yml

- export ANDROID_HOME=~/builds/f2prateek/FoodBot/android-sdk-linux
- export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools

Is there something else I need to be setting up to get this right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update 2014/05**: Travis CI now has official support for Android.

http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/

The workarounds below are not required anymore, unless you want to use it on a
non-Android VM.

---

The issue is most likely with the fact that Travis CI switched over to 64-bit virtual machines. You need to install ia32-libs for Android to run in a 64-bit environment. This can currently be achieved with:

```
sudo apt-get install -qq --force-yes libgd2-xpm ia32-libs ia32-libs-multiarch
```

I wrote a blog post on getting Android builds running on Travis, which covers this as well as other details: http://rkistner.github.com/android/2013/02/05/android-builds-on-travis-ci/

Travis might support Android-specific virtual machines in the future, which will simplify the configuration. Follow the conversation on [issue #56](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-worker/issues/56) for updates on this issue and discussions on the Android-specific VM.

Comment: Yup, been following that for weeks. Thanks for the workaround :)

Comment: I get the following error: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 : Depends: libgphoto2-2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libsane:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: You get an error like that when you try to install only `ia32-libs-multiarch` - you need to use the entire line as I have it above.

Answer (score 3):

This reply covers up to Travis automatic testing. See the [Medium article](https://medium.com/@zurfyx/android-travis-ci-with-autodeploy-api-26-efb6c1863628) for the complete version: automatic testing and deployment.

---

## Travis CI (@ API 26+)

Apparently from API 24 setting up the emulator is a pain on Travis is a pain[[1]](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7425)[[2]](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8188)[[3]](https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-create-android-emulator/issues/13)[[4]](https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-android/issues/228).

*[Sean Barbeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/937715/sean-barbeau), who's been digging through this for a lot more time than I have, has [pretty much considered it impossible](https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-android/commit/03e262d2ca17e2b4ea654640b38d9719bb8e9a3d) to emulate.*

But there is a working and simpler alternative for **API 26+**, which is running the tests with `gradlew` instead of the `adb emulator`. It [seems to have some limitations](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line.html#RunTestsDevice), but it should work. Credits to [PocketHub](https://github.com/pockethub/PocketHub).

```
sudo: required

language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8

before_cache:
  - rm -f  $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
  - rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/*/plugin-resolution/

cache:
  directories:
  - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
  - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
  - $HOME/.android/build-cache

env:
 global:
 - ANDROID_API=26
 - ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS=26.0.2

android:
  components:
  - tools
  - tools # Running this twice get's the latest build tools (https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Setting-up-Travis-CI)
  - platform-tools
  - android-${ANDROID_API}
  - build-tools-${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}
  - extra

script:
- ./gradlew clean test build
```

**Environment variables that you might have to adapt** to your project ones:

Some information should be available either in the `build.gradle` or `AndroidStudio -> Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools`

(if you're building a new project with an updated AndroidStudio you should just pick the latest versions in the following links)

**ANDROID_API**: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

**ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS**: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html

[Example .travis.yml setup](https://github.com/zurfyx/travis-android) (with autodeploy to GitHub releases).

Comment: This only runs the JVM junit tests, and not the instrumented tests.